# How to replace grid columns with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to jQuery/Javascript. This is my first time really constructing my own jQ code without using a tutorial.

I'm using the skeleton grid, and trying to use jQuery to change a four column layout to a six column layout so that my three image wide row will switch to a two image wide row between 500px-800px. I'm not getting any console errors, but it's not working. Anyone see what the issue is with my jQ script?

Note: The "class='four columns portfolio'" is from the Lynda tutorial (but in skeleton.css it refers to it as 'four.columns' which is weird to me). That's something I hadn't seen before.

http://codepen.io/pandathorax/pen/oXEqRg

```
var width = $(window).width();
while ( width > 550 && width <= 801) {
    var columnChange = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
    $(columnChange).removeClass('four.columns').addClass('six.columns');
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your using both jQuery and non-jQuery selectors. If jQuery is acceptable:

```
var width = $(window).width();
while ( width > 550 && width <= 801) {
    $('.row').removeClass('four').addClass('six');
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Cymen. We can use jQuery or JS. I don't know if it's possible to do with just a media query, but I'd really like to solve it with jQ/JS just for the learning experience. 

That said, unfortunately your suggested code didn't work for me, which could easily be something wrong with my HTML/CSS.